# Stop process in R

Tags: r, validation

I have a function which calls a function which checks if a number is positive.

The functioned which is called checks:

```
if(x <= 0) stop("error: not positive")
```

However, this doesn't stop the other processes from happening, it still attempts to continue. I want the stop to stop the entire program and return "invalid arguments".

*EDIT*

Request for mode code:

```r
my.function <- function(x){
  
  #check if positive and not zero 
  if(x <= 0) stop("invalid arguments")

  abc <- c(1,2)  
  return(abc)
}

l <- "hello"
x <- -100

l <- my.function(x)

print(l)
```

Output:

```r
> l <- "hello"
> x <- -100

> l <- my.function(x)

Error in my.function(x) : invalid arguments

> print(l)
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: `x<=0` will be true when x is less than or equal to zero - contradicting your error message

Comment: Thanks for catching that - exactly right. Yeah, I'm not worried about what the error message is, etc. But why it doesn't stop all the processes. Everything seems to continue on regardless.

Comment: Could you post more code? `stop` should definitely halt execution unless wrapped in `try` or similar.

Comment: Added more code as requested. And I would expect the code to stop at l=my.function(x), but it continues to print hello.

Comment: Running the code in an interactive session it will proceed - but if you save the code in a file and `source()` it, no lines after the error will be run.